# VueJS - Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, axios

Although the output is correct. I have this error: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined. I suspect it is because listing is added after ajax call. How do I improve this?

```
<template v-for="status in showStatus">
    <div class="col-sm-1">{{status}}</div>
</template>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: { 
            listing: []
        },
        created: function(){
            axios.get('/getListing')
            .then(function (response) {
                app.listing = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        computed: {
            showStatus(){
                return this.listing[0].status;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is that `<template>` your root template for the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've guessed, this is because `listing` starts as an empty array which is populated at a *later* time.

Your computed property doesn't do any checks for this and `this.listing[0]` will be `undefined` early on.

You just need to add a check to your computed poperty

```js
computed: {
  showStatus () {
    return this.listing[0]?.status || []
  }
}
```

See [*Optional chaining (?.)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) if you haven't seen that syntax before.

---

An alternative would be to initialise `listing` with some safe default data

```js
data: () => ({
  listing: [{ status: [] }]
})
```